# How do I configure grunt-karma to run tests directly when starting a watch?

Tags: karma-runner

I have configured my grunt/karma setup according to https://github.com/karma-runner/grunt-karma

I'm also using it together with grunt-contrib-watch as described under https://github.com/karma-runner/grunt-karma#karma-server-with-grunt-watch

Almost everything works great, but how do I configure karma to perform all tests directly when the watch is started?

I start it with `karma:unit:start watch` but then I must first change a file before the tests are performed.

I have stared at the karma config params at http://karma-runner.github.io/0.8/config/configuration-file.html but still cannot find the correct param.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used grunt-karma before, but the easiest option is probably to configure your watch task, so that it runs it's tasks at startup. This can be done via [options.atBegin](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch#optionsatbegin). So if you take the example from the grunt-karma documentation, you would write:

```
watch: {
    karma: {
        files: ['app/js/**/*.js', 'test/browser/**/*.js'],
        tasks: ['karma:unit:run'],
        options: {
            atBegin: true
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: Indeed it tries to run the tests at startup, but the tests fail beacuse of "No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/". The browser gets opened, but maybe not fast enough?